# Python read from .csv, create list of class objects and do something with it. Returning data as [texthere] instead of texthere causing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I hope that my titel is somewhat clear enough haha.

I am trying to get data from an API and all of that works just fine when I manually put in what I want, but now I am trying to get that data in bulk and therefore want to create a .csv file where python gets data from the API for each entry in that file.

I have created a sample code to illustrate what I am trying to do and where my issue is.

In here we create a person, get his name, age and city, read that data from a .CSV file, put everything in a list and than the API does something with it.

```
import csv

# class definition
class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name, Age, City):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Age = Age
        self.City = City

# using a list, because it's mutable
Persons = []


# reading csv and filling Persons list
with open('ReadCSVTest.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        entity = Person(str(row["Name"]), str(row["Age"]), str(row["City"]))

        # add the new person to the list
        Persons.append(entity)

# output loop, API stuff.
for person in Persons:
    print("Hello " + person.Name)
    print("You are " + person.Age)
    print("And live in " + person.City)
```

The problem is that my API reads this data as [City] instead of a string that says City, and therefore it does not recognize it and won't do anything with it.

I'm guessing that I should be able to convert the output of this little script to reflect just the string instead of [String], but I am not able to figure out how to do this.

I hope I described this clear enough.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in my API and not in this code. It turned out to be one of those issues so obvious that it takes 2 hours to figure out how easy the fix is.

Thanks anyway!